# How to Add/Edit the Context Menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I thought VSCode was "made to be hacked", similar to Atom but for the life of me - I cannot find how to add-to or edit the **"Editor Context Menu"** (*the menu that opens when you right-click (or apparently hit F12)*) in Code Editor.

I have some commands added from an extension that I can run from the "Command Menu" (ctrl-alt-shift-P), but I want those in the context menu.

Comment: I think the context menu cannot be modified as end user. However you can ask the author of the extension to add [menu contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) to the extension. Then the command will be available in the context menu. Further the visibility can be controled by the `when` clause. So the extension could add that command to the context menu, when a setting is set by the user.